My MERN app will not deploy, tell me what im doing wrong?
I have tried multiple times to deploy MERN project and I keep running into issues. First it would run locally but not on a server. Now that i've tried setting up with Azure web app services - it says my app is deployed and waiting for my content. But when I run it locally now nothing happens on submit and doesnt show existing database entries. Any help is appreciated.
Here is the link to the repo - https://github.com/zachmvm/IronWatchSecurity
I tried editing the yml file and that seemed to fix the errors uploading the app to Azure. But it still doesnt show up when I try to visit URL on Azure Web app.

I can see that you are only deploying backend files to web app. Is your web app running on linux or windows?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya On linux. And how do you mean?

I check you workflow file. In the step Deploy to web app  in the package you are just adding backend folder but you are unzipping forntend in fontend folder and backend in backend folder

This worked for me.
yml:
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - mernnodeapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      # Build frontend
      - name: Build frontend
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
        working-directory: frontend/
        
      # Build backend
      - name: Build backend
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
        working-directory: backend/
          
      # Zip artifacts for deployment
      - name: Zip artifacts for deployment
        run: |
          zip -r frontend.zip frontend/*
          zip -r backend.zip backend/*
      # Upload artifacts for deployment job
      - name: Upload artifacts for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: frontend-app
          path: frontend.zip

      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: backend-app
          path: backend.zip


  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download frontend artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: frontend-app

      - name: Unzip frontend artifact for deployment
        run: unzip frontend.zip

      - name: Download backend artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: backend-app

      - name: Unzip backend artifact for deployment
        run: unzip backend.zip
      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'mernnodeapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }}

To deploy from GitHub using publish profile, you need to enable SCM Basic Auth Publishing Credentials


If you are deploying only for backend use command npm run start in correct directory.
if you are deploying frontend, for react app use pm2 serve home/site/wwwroot/frontend/build --no daemon --spa


Note : make sure path or directory is correct for the files

OUTPUT:


